# Django session always closes after browser close

Tags: django

once I set this in settings.py

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

I can't change to set it back and make sessions always open. I tried to set this to False , but no effect.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes, several times

Comment: If you go into the django shell and import your settings, is it set to True there?

Comment: @jcfollower No it is false, but it always closes sessions after browser close